# How to separate transient and steady state solution when using the Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform

When we find the solution of a system using the Laplace transform, it gives a complete solution unlike the differential equation approach which gives the transient part the steady state part separately. Is there a way we can identify which part constitutes the transient part  using the Laplace transform? (Mathematically?)

Comment: When you convert a "block" to Laplace there is no implied transient nor steady-state part. That only comes when you multiply the Laplace transform of the "block" with your desired input waveform (in Laplace form). So, what are you actually asking.

Comment: The Laplace solution and the differential equation solution must be exactly the same. You don't get a different system by analysing it in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

The solution  of a linear system should contain some exponential terms which decay towards zero when time grows towards infinity. Let those exponentials be zero. What's left, that's your steady state response.